# Postgres liquiabsev No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange

Tags: liquibase

Getting No inverse to liquibase.change.core.RawSQLChange created” while running liquibase for postgres env

Answer (score 0):

Check if rollback statement is mentioned. If not just added dummy like
-- rollback select 1

Answer (score 0):

Here are the ways to incidate "no rollback necessary" in liquibase changelogs:

XML:

```
<rollback/>
```

formatted SQL:

```
--rollback not required
```

YAML:

```
rollback:

  - empty: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `No inverse to liquibase change...` indicates :

1. You have not provided rollback sql statement for the changeset
2. auto-rollback statement for sql statement you are using is not known

and hence Liquibase fails to rollback your changeset.

If you want to `skip the rollback` for a changeset, you can achieve that by the ways Daryl has mentioned in his answer.

> Here are the ways to incidate "no rollback necessary" in liquibase
> changelogs:
>
> XML:
>
> `<rollback/>`
>
> formatted SQL:
>
> `--rollback not required`
>
> YAML:
>
> `rollback:`
> `- empty: {}`

Or if you want to have the rollback statements then you can include it by referring to [this rollback documentation link](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/rollback/rollback-by-tag.html).

You can also refer to [my answer on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67017400/how-to-rollback-a-drop-column-in-liquibase/67019210#67019210) for some details on liquibase rollback.